# How can I export all data from a table with millions of rows to csv from Power BI using Power Automate?

Tags: powerbi, power-automate, daxstudio

I already know how to do it using DAX Studio. However, I would like to do it automatically. As the Pbi file provided to me is using a direct query I am very limited to do some tasks. Thanks!

Comment: You should no do that through Power BI. Connect to the datasource directly, avoiding the limitations of Power BI.

Comment: That's the problem. I don't have this access. Only via direct query, that is limited.